# Decimals in jQuery Mobile number input

Tags: jquery-mobile

Working on a jQuery Mobile form with an input for entering dollar amounts. `<input type="number" name="amount"/>` pops up the numeric entry on devices and restricts to number only. But when I enter a decimal amount and attempt to submit the form, it focuses on the amount field and says "Invalid Value."

How do I keep the theme and data type while allowing digits?

Many thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding the step attribute:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.step.float

Example:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" >
```

Comment: That really helped! The official docu sucks completly.

Answer (score 2):

Can also try:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9.]*">
```